# Main nav starts scrolling and then comes back

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On Chrome, the main nav of our wordpress website starts to scroll with the content but then quickly moves back up which creates an unwanted visual hitch.

www.vitrinemedia.ca (check carefully the black top nav to see what I mean)

On safari it's working well though, does anybody know how to fix it?

Thank you,

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce the issue in Chrome 74.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'm just not sure where in the code we could fix this and I thought someone might have an idea.
I also use Chrome 74.

Comment: I see it. Scrolling before the site loads completely results in the site jumping back to the top. OP doesn't know where it is in the code.  My suggestion is to hide #grve-feature-section in your CSS with `display:none;` or remove it from your home page and see if that fixes it - if so - then you know it is based on that section. Why that part - gut feeling...

Comment: @JasonB Thank you, I've added the css to the home page but the hitch is still here :/

Comment: Actually the hitch only appear when I'm logged in in the wordpress admin, that might be due to the wordpress thin menu bar that goes above my menu.